# Build Rest XML body in pentaho

Tags: xml, pentaho

I'm trying to build an xml body(like below) to send as part of my rest call.

```
<Columns>
  <Column>
    <Name>email</Name>
  </Column>
  <Column>
    <Name>firstname</Name>
  </Column>
  <Column>
    <Name>lastname</Name>
  </Column>
</Columns>
```

Using generate rows and Add XML i was able to build below structure

```
<Columns>
   <Column>email</Column>
   <Column>firstname</Column>
   <Column>lastname</Column
</Columns>
```

However adding additional tag (Name) around the values proves to be tricky.

Any pointers in the right direction would be of help.

ktr file in this location: http://pastebin.com/wk81GqLa

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right way of doing it, but it provides the output i'm looking for.

I've added a modified javascript value process with

```
var replval = replace(replace(Columns,'</Column>','</Name></Column>'),'<Column>','<Column><Name>');
```